# Saving and loading in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, function, load, save

I am currently making a simple game (My first) with HTML and Javascript. This is the code for saving:

```
function save()
{
  var save = {
    ducks: ducks,
    ponds: ponds,
    pondCost: pondCost,
    ponds: ponds,
    vacuums: vacuums,
    vacuumCost: vacuumCost,
    vacuum: vacuum,
    llama: llama,
    llamaCost: llamaCost,
   llamas: llamas
  }
  localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};
```

And this is the code for loading:

```
function load()
{
  var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
  if (typeof savegame.ducks !== "undefined") ducks = savegame.ducks;
  if (typeof savegame.ponds !== "undefined") ponds = savegame.ponds;
  if (typeof savegame.pond !== "undefined") pond = savegame.pond;
  if (typeof savegame.pondCost !== "undefined") pondCost = savegame.pondCost;
  if (typeof savegame.vacuums !== "undefined") vacuums = savegame.vacuums;
  if (typeof savegame.vacuum !== "undefined") vacuum = savegame.vacuum;
  if (typeof savegame.vacuumCost !== "undefined") vacuumCost = savegame.vacuumcost;
  if (typeof savegame.llama !== "undefined") llama = savegame.llama;
  if (typeof savegame.llamas !== "undefined") llamas = savegame.llamas;
  if (typeof savegame.llamaCost !== "undefined") llamaCost = savegame.llamaCost;
  document.getElementById('ponds').innerHTML = ponds;
  document.getElementById('vacuums').innerHTML = vacuums;
  document.getElementById('vacuumCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
  document.getElementById('pondCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};
```

I also added a reset feature but as soon as I added this in and pressed the reset button, saving isn't working! (or loading)

```
function reset()
{
  localStorage.removeItem("save")
}
```

All of these buttons are attached to a button in my HTML.

**Play the game in your browser:**
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104187515/TIGWNN/index.html

Comment: I figured it out! i opened up web inspector and saw that 2 variables didn't exist so it couldn't save. i deleted them and some more errors popped up! so now its fixed!

Comment: Puffychesses, I have looked into your work and your game is a great start for a beginner. I would like to help you out with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without fully debugging your code, I'm getting an error when I hit save. Your save function on line 17 is doing:

```
vacuum: vacuum,
```

You have no global variable named vacuum, but you do have one named `vacuums`. That error is halting any further processing.